# Unable to parse diff revision header 'non existent' in tortoise svn?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Created a svn patch with the folder and then applied the base directory and the path file in the review board. It shows that it is unable to parse diff revision header 'non existent' in review board.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe this is a change in tortoise SVN 1.9.x path output used to use (revision 0) to indicate files that didn't exist.  1.9.1+ now uses (nonexistent)

## 1.9.1+ (maybe earlier, only checked 1.9.1 and 1.9.2)

--- BuildIni/Delphi-2007_2600_S3LogUploader.ini (nonexistent)
+++ BuildIni/Delphi-2007_2600_S3LogUploader.ini (working copy)

## 1.8.9

--- BuildIni/Delphi-2007_2600_S3LogUploader.ini (revision 0)
+++ BuildIni/Delphi-2007_2600_S3LogUploader.ini (working copy)

This breaks import of patch files into Review Board (2.0.6 at least) and probably other tools.

It's easy to work around, simply search for nonexistent and replace with revision 0, at least that worked for me.

Comment: Further digging turned up a lot of comments in the SVN users mailing list about inconsistency in this regard.  Seems to be related to files that have been added via SVN copy for the most part.

Answer (score 0):

What's the version you are using? I have faced this problem in TortoiseSVN 1.9 and 1.9.2 (latest version). However it got resolved by using an older version 1.8.11 of TortoiseSVN (TortoiseSVN-1.8.11.26392-x64-svn-1.8.13).

Comment: I am using the latest version 1.9.2

Comment: Can you try downgrading svn to 1.8.11 and check?

Comment: The [earlier answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33681532/737440) by user5556513 also works.